# Prove that, If $f(0)=f(1)=0,$ and $M:=\max _{[0,1]}\left|f^{\prime}\right|,$ then $\int_{0}^{1}|f| \leq \frac{M}{4}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, $M:=\max _{[0,1]}\left|f^{\prime}\right| .$ Prove the following statement.

(a) If $f(0)=f(1)=0,$ then $\int_{0}^{1}|f| \leq \frac{M}{4}$.

Attempt:

By taking $f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)dt$, I am getting  $|f(x)|\leq M x,~x \in [0,1]$. This gives $\int_{0}^{1}|f| \leq \frac{M}{2}$. But how to strengthen the estimate?

Comment: Note you never used $f(1)=0$.  Use it as well to show $|f(x)| \leq M(1-x)$

Comment: $\int_0^1=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|f(x)| = |f(x)-f(0)| \le Mx$ and
$|f(x)-f(1)| \le M(1-x)$, so
$|f(x)| \le M\min(x,1-x)$. Now integrate the upper bound.

Comment: I am not getting how to get the estimate $M/4$

Comment: The integral of the upper bound is the are of an isosceles triangle of height .5 and base 1

Comment: Why is $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le x$?

Comment: Mean value theorem. Notice $f(0)=0$

Comment: ya....i got it, thanks